# What's identification mark for a internal transaction?

Tags: etherscan, internal-transactions

I used Parity tracer, it return a lot of message with many opCode: CREATE, CALL, CALLCODE, DELEGATECALL, and SUICIDE. It may be 60,70 traces.

But when you see in ropsten or etherscan, it show only 1,2 or 3 internal transactions.

Example:

I have a transaction hash: `0xe3c884a2bc63e033ab3110a8bb50156f81e50c72bc329b1471a1aadedeff3850`

- See internal transactions of this transaction:
  https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe3c884a2bc63e033ab3110a8bb50156f81e50c72bc329b1471a1aadedeff3850#internal
- See all traces of this transaction:
  https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xe3c884a2bc63e033ab3110a8bb50156f81e50c72bc329b1471a1aadedeff3850&type=parity#raw

It has only 1 internal transactions but has 16 traces. So how I can filter traces to find internal transactions exactly? Can you give me a sample code? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Currently Etherscan only show operations with non zero Ether transfer, ie it will not show operations that do not involve a transfer of ethers.

Comment: Just to extend a tiny bit. It's true what this answer says. EtherScan doesn't show every trace. Parity shows every trace (even non-eth-transfers). Thus the difference.